# Python Re apply/search TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

Can someone explain why I am getting this error and how to fix it? I am attempting to search a title for a year 98-99 and I want to get the first part (98):

example title: CAR EBC 98-99

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

on the year_min line is where the error is occuring.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

fileinString = 'a.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(fileinString, sep=",")

# split title of df1 into string and year tag min and year tag max
regular_expression = re.compile(r'\d\d-\d\d')

title_string = df1['*Title']


year_min = title_string.apply(lambda x: regular_expression.search(x)[0].split('-')[0])

year_max = df1['*Title'].apply(lambda x: regular_expression.search(x)[0].split('-')[1])

print(year_min)
```

Close Example of it running but It doesnt work:
https://ideone.com/JANVt2

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't know what's inside your data frame.

Comment: quite simply: if `re.search()` doesn't find a match, it returns `None`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/JANVt2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception you're getting is typical for attempting to use bracket notation to access data from a variable containing None.

```
x = None
x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I would say one of your text values in title strings does not contain the pattern you're looking for - for which regular_expression.search(x) returns None.

One way you could go about handling these cases is adding some logic to the function you're applying over the column. Something along the lines of:

```
def extract_pattern(txt):
   match = regular_expression.search(txt)
   if match is None:
      return 'NOT FOUND'
   return match.groups(0).split('-')[0]
year_min = title_string.apply(extract_pattern)
```

Comment: So I have removed the split function so I am just running the following line:
year_min = df1['*Title'].apply(lambda x: regular_expression.search(x))

and this produces results in the following format:
0     <re.Match object; span=(68, 73), match='89-92'>

Comment: How can I 1. get the information with out the <re.Match text and just the match in the variable.

and then do the split on the variable?

Comment: Thats a re.Match object you're getting. You can access the data by using the group method like: match.group(0) (where 0 is the index of the group, as you may match several groups).

Comment: I've added a possible (but not optimal) solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your df1['*Title'] has a value which doesn't match this pattern

When it finds the pattern in the string retuns something

```
In [18]: regular_expression = re.compile(r'\d\d-\d\d')

In [19]: regular_expression.search('12-18')

Out[19]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='12-18'>
```

Where as when doesn't find it returns None

```
In [20]: regular_expression.search('1218') ==None
Out[20]: True
```

and None is not subscriptable
i.e. you can't do None[0]

so in the end what you're effectively doing is

```
In [21]: None[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-4b6604f77809> in <module>
----> 1 None[0]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```